# jQuery, clicked element properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics

how could I build a script, which to get all the elements (if set ID, NAME, CLASS, TYPE OF ELEMENT[div,form...]) of clicked element, please note I am trying to gather data of clicked element by user.

Comment: Create a delegated click handler at the document level using `.on()`. Within the click handler `this` will be the element, so just do whatever it is you want to do with `this.id`, `this.name`, `this.className`, etc.

Comment: `jQuery("*").on("click", function() {console.log(this)})` logs the information of _anything_ the user clicks on.

Comment: @Vld that not's good if user clicks on element it will probably log element>parent>body>html

Comment: I didn't say it was good. It satisfies the requirements, though. Given the lack of any code in the question, I felt it was more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  console.log("ID: " +$(this).attr('id'));
  console.log("Class: " +$(this).attr('class'));
  console.log("Name: " +$(this).attr('name'));
  console.log("Type: " +$(this)[0].tagName);
});
```

```css
.myclass{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid #333;
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv" class="myclass">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes is a property of jQuery DOM object. It is object that contains object for each attribute, and from this the name and value of attribute can be pulled.

```js
$('body>*').click(function() {
  $('.cont').empty()
  // here you get element properties 
  $('.cont').append("tag --> " + this.tagName + "<br>")
 
  //here you get attributes 
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
 
    if(this.specified) {
      $('.cont').append(this.name + ' --> ' + this.value + '<br>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="A" id ="2" markup = "html" something="beacon">A</div><br>
<button class="B" id ="10" markup = "xml" something="beacon">B</button><br>
<span class="C" id ="23" markup = "aa" something="beacon">C</span><br>
<div class="D" id ="19" markup = "cc" something="beacon">D</div><br>

<br>
<br>


<div class="cont">
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need `this.attributes` when `this.id` and `this.name` will already give the id and name (for elements that have a name property). And similar for other properties.

Comment: I don't get you, `$(element).markup` (for example) is `undefined` property, I need the name of the current attribute.

Comment: And I'm referring to html attributes not element object properties

Answer (score 1):

I write this small example for your purpose. Yet another solution.
In this way you can see all clicked object properties. In html:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me"/>
<a href="#">click me</a>
```

In JavaScript:

```
$("body").on("click", "*", function(event) {
  var allProps = [];
  var obj = this;
  while(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
      allProps = allProps.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
      obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
  console.log(allProps);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is working jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zu5pe699/14/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get `this`on the click it will wrap all info required by you

```
 $('#clickMe').on('click',function(){
  console.log(this);
 });
```